# How to sort a Map<String, List<Set<Long>>> by the Set size sum?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can I sort a Map(String, List(Set(Long))) by the Set size sum?
I have a HashMap like this:

```
myMap.put("monday", [[3215, 5654], [5345], [3246, 7686, 4565]]) // 6 Long elements in total
myMap.put("tuesday", [[3215, 5654], [5345, 2879, 6734], [3246, 7686, 4565]]) // 8 Long elements in total
myMap.put("wednesday", [[9845, 2521], [0954]]) // 3 Long elements in total
```

I expect the myMap sorted like this:

```
("tuesday", [[3215, 5654], [5345, 2879, 6734], [3246, 7686, 4565]]) // 8 Long elements in total
("monday", [[3215, 5654], [5345], [3246, 7686, 4565]]) // 6 Long elements in total
("wednesday", [[9845, 2521], [0954]]) // 3 Long elements in total
```

Comment: Maps can only be sorted by key. If you want something sorted, don't use a map. Use a List.

Comment: Depends what you want to do with of course...

Answer (score 5):

Use `LinkedHashMap` for sorting:

```
Map<String, List<Set<Long>>> result = map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(e->e.getValue().stream().mapToInt(Set::size).sum()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Answer (score 1):

You would be able to perform some operations on it, but keeping a `HashMap` sorted on value is indeed not possible.

However, if you know the operations you want to perform on it, you may use the following solution.

```
myMap.entrySet()
     .stream()
     .sorted((entry1, entry2) -> {
         Integer sum1 = getSumOfSetCount(entry1.getValue());
         Integer sum2 = getSumOfSetCount(entry2.getValue());
         return Integer.compare(sum1, sum2);
     })
     .forEach(entry -> // perform operation);
```

With `getSumOfSetCount()` being

```
public int getSumOfSetCount(List<Set<Long>> list) {
    return (int) list.stream()
                     .flatMap(Stream::of)
                     .count();
}
```